# VueJs - one component multiple fiters

Tags: filter, components, vue.js, dry

I have a vue Js component, which outputs data based on a filter

```
Vue.component('talents', {

        template: `<div>
                     <div  v-for="talent in filteredItems" @mouseover="activate" @mouseout="deactivate" v-bind:class="talent.classes"  class="item">
            <div class="vline"></div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="media">{{talent.sectors}}</div>
            <div class="title">{{talent.title}}</div>
            <div class="description">{{talent.description}}</div>
        </div>
          <div class="img">
        <div class="overlay"><a class="button" v-bind:href="talent.link">View project <div class="plus"><span>[</span><span>+</span><span>]</span></div></a></div>     
        <img v-bind:src="talent.image">
    </div>
    `,
```

I would like to reuse the component but apply a different filter to it. Is t his possible?

Comment: You can make this component to accept some prop from parent component, and then you can sent those filtered data from parent as prop to child component.
There is an mixin option https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html, but not sure would it work totally for you..

Comment: yes, it is possible. This link would be helpful, https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html